# Python replace string between tags

Tags: python

I want to make a simple home made bbcode.

Example of a string :

```
s = 'Hello world, this is my website {url}myURL{/url}'
```

I want to replace `{url}myURL{/url}` by `<a href="myURL">myURL</a>`

It will be great if someone has the solution ?

Comment: You can use regex substitution: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: You might want to check out the [bbcode module](https://pypi.org/project/bbcode/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = 'Hello world, this is my website {url}myURL{/url}'
print(re.sub(r"{url}(.*?){\/url}", r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', s))
```

**Output:**

```
Hello world, this is my website <a href="myURL">myURL</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Python String replace() Method**
>
> The `replace() method` replaces a specified phrase with another
>   specified phrase.
>
> Note: All occurrences of the specified phrase will be replaced, if
>   nothing else is specified.
>
> *Syntax:*
>
> string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)

```
s = 'Hello world, this is my website {url}myURL{/url}'
print (s.replace('{url}', '<a href="').replace('{/url}','">myURL</a>'))
```

output:

```
Hello world, this is my website <a href="myURL">myURL</a>
```